# MySQL Join Query GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. (hotels, locations).

I want to retrieve all the locations with a count of number of Hotels in that location.

Right now I have the following query:

```
SELECT locations.*, 
COUNT(*) as no_of_hotels 
FROM locations RIGHT JOIN hotels ON hotels.location_id = locations.id 
GROUP BY locations.id 
ORDER BY no_of_hotels DESC
```

The query works fine, but the problem is, It gives me only the locations with 1 or more hotels. I want to show all the locations (even though the location has no hotels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change to left join:

```
SELECT locations.*, 
       COUNT(distinct hotels.id) as no_of_hotels 
       FROM locations 
       LEFT JOIN hotels ON hotels.location_id = locations.id 
       GROUP BY locations.id 
       ORDER BY no_of_hotels DESC
```

Otherwise probably this is easier to understand:

```
select
  locations.*
  (select count(*) from hotels where hotels.location_id = locations.id) as no_of_hotels 
from
  locations
order by no_of_hotels desc
```

Comment: Left join works, but it gives the value 1 for no_of_hotels, even though there aren't any hotels. 

But the second solution works well.

Comment: I modified a bit. Can you try it? (And probably the second one would give the correct result as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT locations.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM hotels WHERE hotels.location_id = locations.id) AS no_of_hotels FROM locations ORDER BY no_of_hotels DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with INNER JOIN like this

```
SELECT locations.*, 
COUNT(*) as no_of_hotels 
FROM locations INNER JOIN hotels ON hotels.location_id = locations.id 
GROUP BY locations.id 
ORDER BY no_of_hotels DESC
```